# Python regex not matching unless string is copied and pasted

Tags: python, regex, docx

```
import re
from docx import Document
file1=""

document = Document(filename)    
for p in document.paragraphs:
    file1=(file1 + p.text)
print(file1)

pattern=r"""B.*?A"""
searchObj=re.search(pattern, file1, re.M|re.I)

if searchObj:
    print("\n" + searchObj.group())        
else:
    print("\n No match")
```

File1 is essentially: ...B...A...

A Word .DOCX file is read using docx.
Its contents are stored in a string.
Then an attempt is made to find a specific pattern inside this string.
The attempt fails (no match) unless you copy and paste the exact string from the command window (e.g. if you type A into the Python script then no match, but if you copy and paste A from CMD into the Python script, then the match succeeds).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- OS: Windows 10 pro
- Editor: Brackets 1.13
- Python: 3.7.0
- Docx: 0.8.7

Comment: have you checked the type of `file1` ?

Comment: Is the document you're reading in multiple lines?

Comment: I think it's likely that the copy operation is changing the string somehow.  It could be changing newlines, omitting non-printable characters, or something else.  Could you get an array of codepoints in the original string?  (like `map(ord, str)`)

Comment: file1 type: <class 'str'>

Comment: The file is in multiple lines, yes. There is a new line immediately before A. 
I've never used `map(ord, str)`. The output it gives is: `<map object at 0x031879F0>`

Comment: If `typed_str` is the string typed into Python, and `copied_str` is the string copied and pasted, what do `typed_str==copied_str` and `typed_str is copied_str` return? What do `print(list(type_str))` and `print(list(copied_str))` do?

Comment: `typed_str==copied_str` and `typed_str is copied_str` are both `False`
`list(typed_str)=['T', 'O', 'H']` and
`list(copied_str)['Т', 'О', 'Н']`

Comment: What do you get from `[ord(ch) for ch in typed_str]` and `[ord(ch) for ch in copied_str]`?

Comment: `[84, 79, 72]` and
`[1058, 1054, 1053]`

Comment: Looks like the copied_str is Cyrillic [1058, 1054, 1043]. Is it possible to convert the original document to normal characters? Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the letters are Cyrillic. It is not clear how these are to be converted to normal characters. To the computer they are totally distinct characters. They just happen to look the same to a human observer.